# What are file.max and file.FBX of a model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm tring to make a videogame with three.js, so I downloaded a model from internet and I have found inside the directory the following files:

- city.obj
- city.mtl
- city.max
- city.FBX

I understood that the file city.obj allows to load the model, while the file city.mtl applyes the textures to my model. The problem is that the textures are not applied to all model but only to some parts. I thought that the problem is that I didn't load the other two file: city.max and city.FBX

Does anyone think that the problem could be that? What are city.FBX and city.max in a model?
Eventually, How could I load those two files (.max and .FBX)? This is the following code that I used for loading the model from city.obj and the textures from city.mtl

```
new THREE.MTLLoader().setPath('city/').load('city.mtl', function (materials) {
   materials.preload();
   new THREE.OBJLoader().setMaterials(materials).setPath('city/').load('city.obj', 
   function ( object ) {scene.add( object ); }, undefined, undefined );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> What are city.FBX and city.max in a model?

`FBX` is similar to `OBJ` a 3D format. You can load it in `three.js` with `THREE.FBXLoader`. Check out the following official example to see the loader in action:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx

A `.max` file is just a project file format of Autodesk 3ds Max, a digital content creation tool. You normally do not import this file directly in a 3D app.

`three.js R105`